# When should I use partial fractions in generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, partial-fractions

I am currently studying generating functions and I don't understand why should I use partial fraction decomposition when solving $x^n$ coefficient of a question.
For example, in this function

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)^2} $$

Why should I use partial fractions to divide it to this expression

$$\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{2}{1-2x} + \frac{2}{(1-2x)^2} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(x^i - 2(2x)^i + 2 \binom{i+1}{1}(2x)^i\right) $$

to get the coefficient of $x^n$ and not transfer it to sums from the start like

$\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i & \frac{1}{(1-2x)^2} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{i+1}{1}x^i \end{array}$

Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)^2}  = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i * \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{i+1}{1}x^i$$

and then find the coefficient from convolution.

Or this function instead of doing partial fraction I can do this
$$\frac{1 - x^2}{(1-x)^3} = (1-x^2) * \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{i+2}{2}x^i$$

and use convolution again

Comment: The point about generating functions is that there are many techniques and shortcuts, some of which are useful in some cases. For example you could use partial fractions on $\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{1/2}{1+x}+\frac{1/2}{1-x}$ but it is slower than using substitution.  Incidentally,  $\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^i\binom{i+1}{1}x^i$ with a power of $2$

Comment: So both ways are fine and will give the same solution without the miscalculation in my solution?

Comment: Any correct method should give a correct result, so two correct methods should give the same result, though sometimes you end up with a less-than-obvious combinatorial identity and very occasionally that is interesting and new

Comment: Now I understand, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First example:**

The partial fraction decomposition in the first case is a  convenient representation since we can directly derive a closed formula (without sums) from it. Denoting with $[x^n]$ the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series we obtain at a glance
\begin{align*}
[x^n]\left(\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{2}{1-2x} + \frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}\right)
&=1-2\cdot2^{n}+2(n+1)2^n\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=1+n2^{n+1}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, if we consider instead
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)}\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}
\end{align*}
we know the right-hand term admits the binomial expansion
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{n}(-2x)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)(2x)^n\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Multiplication with the term $\frac{1}{1-x}$ has the nice property
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\right)x^n
\end{align*}
to transform coeffcients $a_n$ to the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$. It follows from (2) the wanted coefficient
\begin{align*}
[x^n]\frac{1}{(1-x)}\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)2^k}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Comparison of (1) and (3) gives
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)2^k=1+n2^{n+1}}
\end{align*}
Note, without comparison we need some additional steps in order to simplify (3) into the closed form (1).

**Second example:**

Here we can easily derive the coefficient without partial fraction decomposition. We obtain for $n\geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
[x^n]\frac{1-x^2}{(1-x)^3}&=[x^n]\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}\\
&=[x^n](1+x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^n\\
&=\left([x^n]+[x^{n-1}]\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^n\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=2n+1}
\end{align*}

**Conclusion:** It depends on the specific situation if partial fraction decomposition is the convenient approach or some alternative techniques are more appropriate instead.